# How can I get a network connection to load completely before a user can log in?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory

I am running a domain with a Win2k8R2 DC. I have a login script running that maps network drives for the computers. Some users log in as soon as the computer boots up and the login scripts don't get a chance to run. Is there a way to ensure (possibly through group policy) that all network settings load before the user is allowed to log in?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could enable the **Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon** Group Policy setting.

It lives in **Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon**.

Alternatively, you could map your network drives with Group Policy Preference items, which should eradicate this problem, and the frustration of waiting for crappy drivers or hardware to properly and fully initialise.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I just couldn't locate that group policy. Thanks!!